# How do I store the values of a for loop in an array?

Tags: php

I'm completely new to programming and have been struggling with this for at least a couple of hours. It simply deals 5 cards to a player. This is the code I have:

```
<?php
//setting up arrays
$cardLocation = array();
$suits = array("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs");
$ranks = array("Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack","Queen", "King");

//filling the deck
for($rank=0; $rank<13; $rank++){
  for($suit=0; $suit<4; $suit++){
    $cardLocation[$rank][$suit] = "deck";
  }
}

//dealing the cards to a player
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){

$duplicate = true;

while($duplicate){
  $suit = rand(1, 4);
  $rank = rand(1, 13);
  if($cardLocation[$rank][$suit] == "deck"){
      $cardLocation[$rank][$suit] = "player";
      $duplicate = false;

    }
  }
}

?>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way of storing each value of the for loop into an array and then printing it out. Have had a few ideas but all of them failed. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: A bit offtopic: I'd recommend checking into a `foreach` loop. Basically it runs a loop for each value of an array so you don't have to limit the length in case you change an array later.  Plus it's easier and shorter to write.  try `foreach($ranks as $value)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that a two dimensional array is a requirement, but if it is not you could consider something like this:

```
<?php

const NUMBER_OF_CARDS_TO_DRAW = 5;

$cardLocation = array();
$suits = array("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs");
$ranks = array("Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack","Queen", "King");

//filling the deck
$deck = [];
foreach ($suits as $suit) {
    foreach ($ranks as $rank) {
        $deck[] = "$suit $rank";
    }
}

// http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php
shuffle($deck);

$playerHand = [];

for ($i=0;$i<NUMBER_OF_CARDS_TO_DRAW;$i++) {
    // http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php
    $randomCard = array_shift($deck);
    if (is_null($randomCard)) {
        // this happens if you try to draw too many cards
        break;
    }
    $playerHand[] = $randomCard;
}

print_r($playerHand);
```